# discord.py slash commands predefined time format

Tags: python, discord.py

[image]

How do I ask a user to output in a predefined time format in slash commands, like in this bot, it is asking user to type time like 1m(for 1 minute) 3w(for 3 weeks, etc), I have searched everywhere for this but I found nothing about this and I have no idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im pretty sure you can use `.endswith()` something like this:

```
if length.endswith(“m”):
    length = length[:-1]
    length = int(length) # now you have an int amount of the minutes and you can do:

    length / 60 # for hours etc
    length * 60 # for seconds

if length.endswith(“w”):
    length = int(length[:-1]) # idk if this will work but if not just use a second line to convert to int like the example for minutes
    length = length * 604800 # for seconds
```

You didnt specify what you’ll be using so imma assume your converting everything to seconds but if not just change the code for that